# Why my SCons parallel build sometime fails

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, scons

### Problem :

We have a quite huge project and we would like a lot to be able to do parallel build.  After many tests, I saw strange behaviors from SCons:

1. Sometime parallel build works (very few time)
2. Sometime parallel build fails on component A
3. Sometime parallel build fails on component B
4. Fails on C, or D etc etc...

See an exemple of one fail output from scons :

```
Install file: "build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\common\win32\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib" as "LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib"
cl /Fobuild\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\ASREngineApp\win32\VrxThinProtocolDelegateASR.obj /c sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\ASREngineApp\VrxThinProtocolDelegateASR.cpp /TP /nologo -Od -D_DEBUG -RTC1 -MDd -Z7 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -DWINDOWS -D_MBCS -DNOMINMAX -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -W3 -nologo -GS -GR -EHa -wd4290 -wd4996 -wd4995 -TP -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 -D_WINDLL /Iinterface\asom\api /Ifwk\simulation_fwk\utils /ILINK\include /Ibuild\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\ASREngineApp\win32 /Isr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\ASREngineApp /IC:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\include /IC:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\ACE+TAO-6.1.3_vs2010\ACE_wrappers /IC:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\loki-0.1.5_vs2010\include /IC:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\verbyx_vrx_r6.1.3\include /Z7
Install file: "build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win32\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib" as "LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib"
link /nologo /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /DEBUG /NOLOGO /dll /out:build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll /implib:build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.lib /LIBPATH:LINK\lib\win32 /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib secur32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib ws2_32.lib Winmm.lib iphlpapi.lib Rpcrt4.lib Psapi.lib avrt.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Messaging-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Scheduler-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_SchedulerProxy-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Logger-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Configuration-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Sockets-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_AdacelBase-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_TransportLayer-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib /PDB:build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\vc100.pdb /DEBUG build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerClient.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerServer.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\DllMain.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerClient.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerServer.obj
VrxThinProtocolDelegateASR.cpp
LINK : build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib'
```

SCons complains that *libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib* is not found, but few line above, SCons says that the file is copied at the right place!  What's wrong here?  Is it possible the *Install* file is not quick enough and SCons tries to compile *ASRNetworkLayer.dll* before file is completely install?

Someone told my that the anti virus might be problematic.  This folder should not be scan by our antivirus, but I do not completely trust IT...

---

### SConscript :

The following is the SConscript that build ASRNetworkLayer.dll

```
Import('common_env')
#Grab a copy of the top environment (the one sent by the SConstruct file)
common_env = common_env.Clone()
#Because this component is compiled in both win32 and win64.
if (common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] == "win32") or (common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] == "win64"):
    #Grabs the library name, the name should look like libpath_of_current_component-(debug/opt)
    libName = common_env.libName()
    dllName = 'ASRNetworkLayer.dll'
    impLibName = 'ASRNetworkLayer.lib'
    common_env.USE_BOOST()
    common_env.sharedLib()
    
    #All the libraries the dll needs.
    libSuffix = common_env['ENV']['OPTSUFF'] + '.lib'
    libraries = [
    'libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Messaging-' + libSuffix,
    'libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Scheduler-' + libSuffix,
    'libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_SchedulerProxy-' + libSuffix,
    'libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Logger-' + libSuffix,
    'libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Configuration-' + libSuffix,
    'libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Sockets-' + libSuffix,
    'libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_AdacelBase-' + libSuffix,
    'libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_TransportLayer-' + libSuffix,
    'libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-' + libSuffix,
    'libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-' + libSuffix]

    common_env.Append(LIBS = libraries)
    #Sources of the library.
    sources = Glob('*.cpp')
    #Creates the library
    common_env.Library(common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + "/" + libName, sources)
    #Install (copy) the library in LINK/lib/winX
    common_env.installInLink(libName)
    #Creates the program
    common_env.SharedLibrary(common_env['ENV']['CONFIG'] + "/" + dllName, sources)
    #Install (copy) the dll in LINK/bin/winX  and LINK/dynlib/winX
    common_env.installInLink(dllName)
    #Install (copy) the implib in LINK/lib/winX
    common_env.installInLink(impLibName)
```

---

### Tree:

The following is a (really) small part of my tree.  I did an analysis of me dependency tree and everything looks fine.(I could not find the installation of the problematic .lib though.)  Maybe someone could see something wrong in there?

```
link /nologo /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /DEBUG /NOLOGO /dll /out:build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll /implib:build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.lib /LIBPATH:LINK\lib\win32 /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib secur32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib ws2_32.lib Winmm.lib iphlpapi.lib Rpcrt4.lib Psapi.lib avrt.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Messaging-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Scheduler-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_SchedulerProxy-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Logger-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Configuration-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Sockets-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_AdacelBase-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_TransportLayer-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib /PDB:build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\vc100.pdb /DEBUG build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerClient.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerServer.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\DllMain.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerClient.obj build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerServer.obj
Install file: "build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.lib" as "LINK\lib\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.lib"
link /nologo /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /DEBUG /NOLOGO /DELAYLOAD:ASRNetworkLayer.dll /DELAYLOAD:ASREngineAppRecognizer32.dll /OUT:build\debug\sr\speech\ASREngineApp\app\win32\win32\ASREngineApp.exe /LIBPATH:LINK\lib\win32 /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\ACE+TAO-6.1.3_vs2010\ACE_wrappers\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\loki-0.1.5_vs2010\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\verbyx_vrx_r6.1.3\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\DirectX0610\lib\x86 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib secur32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib ws2_32.lib Winmm.lib iphlpapi.lib Rpcrt4.lib Psapi.lib avrt.lib aced.lib lokid.lib vrx32.lib winmm.lib Setupapi.lib dsound.lib dxguid.lib delayimp.lib ASRNetworkLayer.lib ASREngineAppRecognizer32.lib libsr_speech_ASREngineApp-debug.lib libsr_speech_common_arch-debug.lib libsr_speech_Recognizer_Verbyx_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_TransportLayer-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_SpeechProtocol_Protocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_common_arch-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_VCSASREngineApp-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_DirectSoundASREngineApp-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_SpeechProtocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_SpeechProtocolASREngineApp-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_log_utils-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_config-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_vcs_utils-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_voice_utils-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_drivers-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_mgt-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_utils-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Messaging-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Scheduler-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Logger-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Configuration-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Sockets-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_AdacelBase-debug.lib /PDB:build\debug\sr\speech\ASREngineApp\app\win32\win32\vc100.pdb /DEBUG build\debug\sr\speech\ASREngineApp\app\win32\ASREngineMain.obj
link /nologo /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /DEBUG /NOLOGO /dll /out:build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\win32\VerbyxRecognizer.dll /implib:build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\win32\VerbyxRecognizer.lib /LIBPATH:LINK\lib\win32 /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\ACE+TAO-6.1.3_vs2010\ACE_wrappers\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\ACE+TAO-6.1.3_vs2010\ACE_wrappers\TAO\tao /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\ACE+TAO-6.1.3_vs2010\ACE_wrappers\TAO\orbsvcs\orbsvcs /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\ACE+TAO-6.1.3_vs2010\ACE_wrappers\TAO\tao\PortableServer /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\loki-0.1.5_vs2010\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\verbyx_vrx_r6.1.3\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\xerces-c-3.1.1_vs2010\Build\Win32\VC10\Debug /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\DirectX0610\lib\x86 /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wxp\i386 /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\delcom-1.0\lib /LIBPATH:C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\openspliceDDSV6.4.140407-win32-vs2010\lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib secur32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib ws2_32.lib Winmm.lib iphlpapi.lib Rpcrt4.lib Psapi.lib avrt.lib aced.lib taod.lib TAO_PortableServerd.lib TAO_CosNamingd.lib TAO_RTEventd.lib TAO_RTSchedd.lib TAO_Svc_Utilsd.lib TAO_AnyTypeCoded.lib TAO_RTEvent_Skeld.lib TAO_RTEvent_Servd.lib lokid.lib vrx32.lib xerces-c_3D.lib winmm.lib Setupapi.lib dsound.lib dxguid.lib hid.lib DelcomDLL.lib ddsdatabase.lib dcpsgapi.lib ddsos.lib dcpssacpp.lib ddskernel.lib libsr_speech_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_common_arch-debug.lib libsr_speech_common_dds-debug.lib libsr_speech_SpeechProtocol_Protocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ASRNetworkLayerDll-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_TransportLayer-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_common_arch-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_VCS-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_DirectSound-debug.lib libsr_speech_AudioProvider_Verbyx_SpeechProtocol-debug.lib libsr_speech_Recognizer_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_Recognizer_Verbyx_common-debug.lib libsr_speech_ContextualPostProcessor-debug.lib libhw_common_hw_HIDDeviceFactory_src-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_events_src-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_rtEventServices_src_RTECFactory-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_rtEventServices_src_rt_event_service-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_drivers-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_mgt-debug.lib libfwk_audio_fwk_src_filter_graph_utils-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_log_utils-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_config-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_vcs_utils-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_network-debug.lib libfwk_voice_fwk_utils_src_voice_utils-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Messaging-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Scheduler-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_SchedulerProxy-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Logger-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Configuration-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Sockets-debug.lib libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_AdacelBase-debug.lib libfwk_network_dds_simd_cpp_api_src_dds-debug.lib libfwk_network_dds_simd_cpp_api_src_dds_peer-debug.lib /PDB:build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\win32\vc100.pdb /DEBUG build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\AsrResultInspector.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\AsrResultVerbyxBuilder.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\IVrxEngineFactory.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\SisrErrorHandler.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\SisrInterpretationParser.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\VrxASR.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\VrxDynamicGrammarManager.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\VrxSpeechController.obj build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\win32\VrxThinProtocolEngine.objx
Install file: "build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll" as "LINK\bin\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll"
Install file: "build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll" as "LINK\dynlib\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll"
.
.
.
|   | | | | |     | +-LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib
  |   | | | | |     | | +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win32\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib
  |   | | | | |     | |   +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win32\ThinProtocol.obj
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocol.cpp
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocol.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\fwk\embedded_fwk\types.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\types.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\types_posix.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE
  |   | | | | |     | |   +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win32\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.obj
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.cpp
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\speech\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocol.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\fwk\embedded_fwk\types.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\types.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\types_posix.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE
  |   | | | | |     | |   +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\win32\ThinProtocolMessaging.obj
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocolMessaging.cpp
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\fwk\embedded_fwk\protocol.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\fwk\embedded_fwk\Utils.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\speech\Logger.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\speech\ThinProtocolMessaging.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\protocol.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\Utils.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\common\Logger.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocolMessaging.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\AdacelBaseExport.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\types.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\ThreadIncludes.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\include\boost\format.hpp
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\fwk\embedded_fwk\MessageConverter.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\speech\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\include\boost\lexical_cast.hpp
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\types_posix.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\include\boost\config.hpp
                            +-   (following is a tons of boost)
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-fwk\embedded_fwk\src\AdacelBase\MessageConverter.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocolMessageDefinitions.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\include\boost\call_traits.hpp
                            +-   (following is a tons of boost)
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ThinProtocol\ThinProtocol.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-LINK\include\adacel\fwk\embedded_fwk\types.h
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\boost-1.47.0_vs2010\include\boost\detail\call_traits.hpp
                            +-   (following is a tons of boost)
  |   | | | | |     | |   | +-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE
  |   | | | | |     | |   +-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\lib.EXE
.
.
.
  |   | | +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer
  |   | | | +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll
  |   | | | | +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32
  |   | | | |   +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\ASRNetworkLayer.cpp
  |   | | | |   +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.obj]
  |   | | | |   +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\ASRNetworkLayerClient.cpp
  |   | | | |   +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerClient.obj]
  |   | | | |   +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\ASRNetworkLayerDll.sc
  |   | | | |   +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\ASRNetworkLayerServer.cpp
  |   | | | |   +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerServer.obj]
  |   | | | |   +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\DllMain.cpp
  |   | | | |   +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\DllMain.obj]
  |   | | | |   +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\IASRNetworkLayerClient.cpp
  |   | | | |   +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerClient.obj]
  |   | | | |   +-sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\IASRNetworkLayerServer.cpp
  |   | | | |   +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerServer.obj]
  |   | | | |   +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32
  |   | | | |     +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerClient.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerServer.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\DllMain.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerClient.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerServer.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Messaging-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Scheduler-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_SchedulerProxy-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Logger-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Configuration-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Sockets-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_AdacelBase-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_TransportLayer-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     +-build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.exp
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerClient.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\ASRNetworkLayerServer.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\DllMain.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerClient.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\IASRNetworkLayerServer.obj]
  |   | | | |     | +-C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Messaging-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Scheduler-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_SchedulerProxy-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Logger-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Configuration-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_Sockets-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libfwk_embedded_fwk_src_AdacelBase-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_TransportLayer-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_ThinProtocol-debug.lib]
  |   | | | |     | +-[LINK\lib\win32\libsr_speech_ASRNetworkLayer_common-debug.lib]  
  
  .
  .
  .
    +-LINK
  | +-LINK\bin
  | | +-LINK\bin\win32
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\aced.dll
  | |   | +-C:\svn\3rdParty\3rdPartyPackages\ACE+TAO-6.1.3_vs2010\ACE_wrappers\lib\aced.dll
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\apdirectSound.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\AudioProvider\DirectSound\win32\win32\apdirectSound.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\app_manager-debug.exe
  | |   | +-[build\debug\fwk\voice_fwk\app_manager_service\src\win32\win32\app_manager.exe]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\app_manager.exe
  | |   | +-[build\debug\fwk\voice_fwk\app_manager_service\src\win32\win32\app_manager.exe]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\apspeechProtocol.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\AudioProvider\SpeechProtocol\win32\win32\apspeechProtocol.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\apvcs.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\AudioProvider\VCS\win32\win32\apvcs.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\ASREngineApp-debug.exe
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASREngineApp\app\win32\win32\ASREngineApp.exe]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\ASREngineApp.exe
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASREngineApp\app\win32\win32\ASREngineApp.exe]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\ASREngineAppRecognizer32.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\ASREngineApp\win32\win32\ASREngineAppRecognizer32.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\ASREngineSpawner-debug.exe
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASREngineSpawner\win32\win32\ASREngineSpawner.exe]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\ASREngineSpawner.exe
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASREngineSpawner\win32\win32\ASREngineSpawner.exe]
  | |   +-LINK\bin\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll]
  
    | +-LINK\dynlib
  | | +-LINK\dynlib\win32
  | |   +-LINK\dynlib\win32\apdirectSound.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\AudioProvider\DirectSound\win32\win32\apdirectSound.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\dynlib\win32\apspeechProtocol.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\AudioProvider\SpeechProtocol\win32\win32\apspeechProtocol.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\dynlib\win32\apvcs.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\AudioProvider\VCS\win32\win32\apvcs.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\dynlib\win32\ASREngineAppRecognizer32.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\Recognizer\Verbyx\ASREngineApp\win32\win32\ASREngineAppRecognizer32.dll]
  | |   +-LINK\dynlib\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll
  | |   | +-[build\debug\sr\speech\ASRNetworkLayer\ASRNetworkLayerDll\win32\win32\ASRNetworkLayer.dll]
```

Comment: If you think that Virus scanning has something to do with this issue, running the build on a separate machine (or laptop) that you have under full control should help. Please make this experiment and report back your findings. In the SCons mailing archives of September 2016 you'll also find an extended discussion about a seemingly related problem (see https://pairlist4.pair.net/pipermail/scons-users/2016-September/thread.html).

Comment: @dirkbeachle I'll be back with further experiments. Alternatively, as a work around, what do you think if, for my `.exe` and `.dll`, instead of linking to `LIBPATH=LINK/lib/win32`, I link directly to variant dir `LIB=#/build/pathToMyFile.lib`. It may resolve the `Install` problem, I won't rely on a copy action from build to `LINK` folder to access a `.lib`. ... let me know

Comment: I think that this kind of shotgun surgery will probably hurt you in the long run. Find and fix the real problem instead...experience tells that it's most often a custom builder or some over-configured setup that gives spurious problems with parallel builds.